# Xcode error when creating IPA: Doesn't match entitlements file value for application-identifier

Tags: xcode, code-signing, ipa, xcode11, code-signing-entitlements

[image: 1]]

I had to upgrade a client iOS project from Swift3 to Swift4 to Swift5 in Xcode 11. Everything works fine, and I am able to create an archive. When I try to Distribute however by creating a QA scheme release build I run into the error as seen in the image. Does anyone know what could be the issue? The app has a Siri extension and the bundle id's (changed for privacy) are com.companyname.appname & com.companyname.appname.Siri respectively. I was previously able to distribute without issues using Xcode 9. Nothing has changed with regards to the code signing files i.e. certificate & profile. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix the issue by manually changing the dynamic bundle identifier to the one required by the signing profile

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Where can you see the application id required by the signing profile? I'm looking everywhere and don't see anything. I'd be forever grateful for a little help. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey @Bryan Deemer, i was having the issue because the bundle identifier field when you select the target was a macro in my case. Make sure that the bundle identifier that is linked to your code signing profile is entered exactly the same in the bundle identifier field i.e. if the bundle id for the profile is com.abccompany.xyzapp then you have to enter it exactly the same in the bundle id for the target. Hope this helps.